# Yii2 bootstrapp modal not popping up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2, twig

i'm using yii2 for development but i faced a problem
when i'm using these codes in view , modal not popping up (when i click on the button nothing happens) 
i cant use

```
  <?php 
         Modal::begin([ ...
```

because i'm doing these in a .twig file and also the embed php costs speed of pages loading

```
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                    Button</button>
```

```
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
//just html stuff

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" style="width:100%">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
<?php
Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<h2>Show Modal</h2>',
    'toggleButton' => false,
    'id' => 'modal-opened',
    'size' => 'modal-lg'
]);

echo 'Modal Opened';

Modal::end();
?>

<?= Html::button('Open Modal', ['id' => 'modal-btn', 'class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>

<?php

$this->registerJs(
    <<<JS
        $('#modal-btn').on('click', function (event) {
                 $('#modal-opened').modal('show');
        });
     JS
    );
?>
```

Dont Forget to import the Modal Library:

```
 use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
```

Answer (score 0):

well i found my solution so i'll share it for anyone that have this problem

in my action in the controller :

```
$modalView = $this->renderPartial('ingredients-modal-content.twig');
$this->view->params['modalView'] = $modalView;
//and another action codes like rendering mainview and etc
```

so we can do whatever we want with twig and our view that iniside ingridients-modal-content.twig or send params to it and ..

in ingridients-modal-content.twig :

```
<form action="/cars/add-cars" method="post"  class="form-group" id="repairmen">
<div class="col-md-4  pull-right" style ="padding:0px; " >
    <input type="submit" id="repairmen" class="btn btn-success" style="width:100%;" value = "Add"></input>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4  pull-right" style ="padding:0px;" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="repairmen_name" placeholder="ID" style = "text-align:center;" name="product_id" >
</div>
<div class="col-md-4  pull-right" style ="padding:0px;" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="repairmen_name" placeholder="Name" style = "text-align:center;" name="product_name" >
</div>
</form>
<table class="table" style="
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right !important;
">

<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>{{item.ID}}</td>
<td>{{item.Name}}</td>
<td>{{item.Price}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" style="width:100%">submit</button>
```

next in our main.php (or another layout file)

```
<?php

Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<h4>title</h4>',
    'id'     => 'model',
    'size'   => 'model-lg',
]);
    if (isset($this->params['modalView'])){
echo $this->params['modalView'];
    };    Modal::end();

?>
```

and for opening modal in our mainview that will render in main.php in the         `<?= $content ?>`
in a button just do this :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#model">
button name</button>
```

that's it